Is there a way to call GOOGLEFINANCE that works for today's date as well as historical data?
In google sheets, if I want today's share price of e.g. AAPL, I can use:
=GOOGLEFINANCE("AAPL")
If I want the historical price for a particular date, I can the following formula, with A1 containing the date:
=index(GOOGLEFINANCE("NASDAQ:AAPL","price",A1,3),2,2)
The latter works fine for all dates except for today's date. Is there a way to call GOOGLEFINANCE (or potentially another function or formula) in such a way that it works both for historical dates as well as the current date?
Edit:
I specifically am trying to find a formula that works for any given historic date as well as today (or even a custom script if that's what it takes - but I can do that myself, I'm just beyond surprised and frustrated that this doesn't seem possible with a basic formula!?).
The single value being returned should be the price on the day referenced in A1. With historic dates, this works with:
index(GOOGLEFINANCE("NASDAQ:AAPL", "price", A1),2,2)

But, if A1 contains today's date, the formula doesn't work, at least not until markets have closed. How to make it work during the current day, in such a way that it will still work tomorrow using the same formula?

[edit] your question to include sample data and a mockup of your desired result.


In google sheets, if I want today's share price of AAPL, I can use:
=GOOGLEFINANCE("AAPL")


Per: Support > GOOGLEFINANCE

That is not "today's share price" but the most recent price delayed by to 20 minutes.
If any date parameters are specified, the request is considered historical and only the historical attributes are allowed.  


You could try combining two GOOGLEFINANCE formulas but you'd need to address the different types of results:
=QUERY(
  { GOOGLEFINANCE("NASDAQ:AAPL", "price", "11/18/2024", 3);
    NOW(), GOOGLEFINANCE("AAPL") },
  "Order by Col1 Desc", 1) 


Example adapting combined formula
Shows how the formulas above can be used dynamically based on whether the end date is today.

Returns historical close prices based on an end date and a maximum number of days (markets may not be open for all historical dates).
Includes the current price if the end date is today.
Sample values used:

End date in A2
Max history in B2



=LET(
   dt,A2, td,dt=TODAY(), daze,B2-td,
   hist,REDUCE(1/0,SEQUENCE(3,1,,-1), LAMBDA(a,v,
     IF(ISERROR(a),
       GOOGLEFINANCE("NASDAQ:AAPL", "price", dt-daze, daze), a))),
   QUERY(IF(td,IFNA(VSTACK(hist,{dt,GOOGLEFINANCE("AAPL")})),hist),
   "Order by Col1 Desc", 1))

Example using Today's date

Example using yesterday's date


Thx. This is helpful but it doesn't really solve my issue. I need to be able to have this formula work with today's date in (say) A10 as well as any other date. I'll try and add some more context to the original question to explain.
